# How to selectively render part of an ocean which is inside a round object?

Tags: rendering, ocean-simulation

Once you see the image of the problem I'm having, it makes it much more sense what my problem is.

[image: My problem]

How do I make it so the ocean doesn't render outside of the cup object? You can see it towards the bottom left of the image

Comment: Why don't you just delete it?

Comment: @VinceScalia What if the ocean is animated?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using a boolean modifier:

1. Create a cylinder the same size of the inside of your cup:

   [image]
2. Add a boolean modifier and an edge-split modifier to the ocean object, with the cylinder object set as the *target*:

   [image]

Make sure the cylinder is set to be hidden in the render, so it doesn't get in the way:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to make the camera a custom shape (like to render through a telescope, for example)? I know you could use compositing, but maybe that could be another way to achieve the same effect. Maybe I should open another question lol.

Comment: @RolandiXor Not too sure what you mean.. But it does sound like an interesting question ;)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I still am having an issue - the boolean modifier is for some reason making it so the ocean turns into a cylinder, with none of the ocean effects.

Comment: @TheKitchenSink Make sure the part  of the ocean you want fits inside the cylinder (i.e. not to high or too low). Also make sure the *operation* of the boolean modifier is set to *Intersect*.

Comment: @gandalf3 I made sure that it was in the cylinder, and the boolean is set to intersect. Is it possible that my dynamic paint modifier is interfering? I do have one, but all it is doing is putting down weight paint to move something along in the cup. I am using cycles to render, so might that have something to do with it? Thanks for all the help so far! I have a feeling that I am on the right track at this point!

Comment: Could be a problem with the normals. Is it possible you could upload your .blend for closer inspection? I don't think dynamic paint or the render engine would interfere..

Comment: [It's here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/65knj7055jojiq7/getondaboatproj.blend?dl=0) If there is a lot of stuff wrong, that is probably because I am new to blender.

Comment: It looks like it's working here.. The cylinder is obscuring the ocean, but that can be fixed by hiding it with `H`. To hide it in the render you'll have to click the camera icon in the outlinder. (See the last screenshot in the answer)

Comment: Hrmmmm... I opened it up again, and the problem was resolved. Huh. Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would create a circular mask texture, and apply it to the alpha of the ocean object. That should allow you to still animate it.